# How to read a text file and write it word by word into another file in python?

Tags: python, file

I have a text file like this :

```
this is a text file.
```

I want to save it into another file like this:

```
this
is
a
text
file
```

Each word comes into new line.
I also have this very simple code :

```
with open("test.txt", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            print(word)
            with open("test1.txt","a") as f1:
                f1.write(word)
```

But after printing, all the words will write stick together.
can you give me a hand? (just a little hint what should I do)

Comment: `f1.write("\n".join(line.split()))`

Comment: This is such a dupe that I'm not even going to bother looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line = 'this is a text file'
line = line.replace(' ', '\n')
print(line)
```

output:

```
this
is
a
text
file
```

Use method above for open and write your file

Answer (score 5):

When you do:

`for word in line.split():`

Actually you are iterating through this list:

`['this', 'is', 'a', 'text', 'file.']`

Because you `split` over whitespaces. Then when you wrote it back to `"test1.txt","a"`, you are writing what's in that list all together without any delimiter or space, so this is your output:

`thisisatextfile.`

Now, if you want every word on each line, just write each word concatenated with `"\n"`, (new line character).

I've made some changes to your code, should look like this:

```
with open("test.txt", 'r') as f, open("test1.txt", 'w') as f1:
    for line in f:
        f1.write('\n'.join(line.split()))
        f1.write('\n')
```

Let's thave a closer look on the most important line: `f1.write('\n'.join(line.split()))`.

- `str.split()` will split a string into a list at white space character(s). (tab(s), space(s), newline(s)).
  So the result of `'word1    word2\nword3\tword4'.split()` will be `['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4']`.
- `str.join(<iterable>)` joins an iterable with the given string together.
  The result of `'\n'.join(['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4'])` is `'word1\nword2\nword3\nword4'`

Comment: You may want to remove some special characters in a real word example first. Like quotes, punctuation etc.

Comment: can you explain this line `f1.write('\n'.join(line.strip().split()))`

Comment: The `strip` is not needed. It removes white space at the beginning and end of a str. Which also will be done by `.split()`.

Answer (score 1):

This simple script should solve your problem:

```
 f=open("test.txt")
 fw=open("test1.txt", 'w')
 for line in f.readlines():
     for word in line.split(" "):
         print(word)
         fw.write(word+"\n")
 fw.close()
```

Comment: Please give stylistically proper answers. You should always use the `with` statement for such things.

Comment: Also just calling `.split()` will split at any whitespace, not just at single spaces. Which might be more what is wanted. Streaming the file will also be better.

Comment: @Erfan You should accept the answer by IronFist, it's better in every way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34706100/3838691

Answer (score 1):

You should open your output file only once.

```
with open("test.txt", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    with open("test1.txt","w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                print(word)
                f1.write(word + '\n')
```

But if you want to stick with your solution, just add `+ '\n'` after `word`. This will create a line break after the words you add to the file.

Answer (score 1):

`write` don't write anything you don't tell it to write, so you have to tell it that write a new line `"\n"` explicitly. Alternatively you can use the print function that automatically put the new line, to get the desire result like this:

```
print(word,file=f1)
```

that is in python 3, in python 2 is

```
print >>f1, word
```

in your case that would be

```
with open("test.txt") as f, open("test1.txt","a") as f1:
    for line in f:
        temp="\n".join(line.split())
        print(temp)
        print(temp,file=f1)
```

that way what you see is what you get

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for the following, assuming test.txt is the input and out.txt is the output:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
     o = f.read()
with open('out.txt', 'a') as f:
     f.write('\n'.join(o.split()))
```